# Lambda is returning headers in body of request

Tags: express, curl, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using serverless to deploy my express js application in lambda.  The weird thing is that some apis are returning headers in the body of the response I am not sure why this is happening.  Here is my serverless YAML file:

```
org: test
app: test-api
# serverless.yml
service: test-api

package:
  exclude:
   #- node_modules/**
   - __tests__/**

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs10.x
    region: us-east-1
    environment:
        SERVICE_NAME: ${self:service}

plugins:
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, dev}
  domains:
    prod: api.test.com
    dev: dev-api.test.com

  customDomain:
    basePath: "${self:provider.environment.SERVICE_NAME}"
    domainName: ${self:custom.domains.${self:custom.stage}}
    stage: "${self:custom.stage}"
    createRoute53Record: true

functions:
  test-api:
    handler: build/app.handler
    environment:
        stage: ${self:custom.stage}
    events:
      - http:
          path: v1/s
          method: GET
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: v1/sc
          method: GET
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: v1/s/{s}
          method: GET
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: v1/cs
          method: POST
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: v1/s
          method: POST
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: v1/s/{s}
          method: DELETE
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: v1/s/{s}
          method: PUT
          cors: true
```

Here is what the response looks like:

curl -d '{"c":"test"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://dev-api.test.com/test-api/v1/cs

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Not Modified
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: sessionId
Vary: Origin
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 55
ETag: W/"37-vmzwGqI9Wb8ACGS7qhhE3/JBqt4"
Date: Fri, 24 Apr 2020 12:30:41 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{"rsp":{"msg":{"s":[],"c":{}},"err":null}
```

Any idea if its the serverless yaml or some other configuration?

Comment: any ideas on this?

Comment: unless you change something on the integration response on the  api gateway, this configuration should respond with headers in the body. But yet again  I don't get what are the headers you are referring to? At least what you shared looks like a normal curl response

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this, contacted serverless support and they said there was a bug and now it has been fixed.  Just need to update serverless and it was resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you enabled the -i option of `curl`? Has curl an alias?